# Reloading jquery events issue after updation in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery

I have got an issue after updation in UpdatePanel. The issue is the jquery events are not working/firing after the updation in UpdatePanel. At first time, the jquery events work, but not after the updation in UpdatePanel. If I remove the UpdatePanel, the problem is solved. But I have to use the UpdatePanel.

Can you give me a solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the possible reasons for this is that the `UpdatePanel` replaces elements in the DOM that had jquery events attached to them which of course nullifies those events. One possible solution would be to use the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to register events but it works only with some events.

If you can't use the `live` function you will need to reattach those events once the `UpdatePanel` has [finished](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx) replacing DOM elements:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function(sender, args) {
    // TODO: reattach your jquery event handlers
});
```

Comment: for using .live(), can we use under normal jquery ? Or should we have to download any plugin/javascript file ?

Comment: `.live()` function is part of jquery (see the link in my post) so you can use it directly.

Comment: ok...let me try....should we use .live() on each time the UpdatePanle executes or at page load itself ?

Comment: Can you just give me sample code of registering livequery plugin for a method ? Also the page load. for example I have two methods "draggable" and "droppable".This is waht I had written : 

$(document).ready(function() {
            if (jQuery.livequery)
                jQuery.livequery.registerPlugin("draggable", "droppable");
            InitializePage();
        });

        function InitializePage() {

            $(".draggable").live("draggable",{ helper: 'clone', scroll: false });

            BindDropEvent();
        }

Comment: function BindDropEvent() {

            $(".droppable").live("droppable",{
                drop: function(ev, ui) {
               }
            });
        }

Comment: .live() works only with basic events. I highly doubt that it works with `droppable`. Read the documentation of supported events.

Comment: Hey Darin. The problem is solved. I had to correct in the jquery javascript file. Now its working in UpdatePanel. Thanks for your help too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the Events or the functions that you want to execute even after the page postbacks as the elements do not remember the events attached to them after postback..

So you need call them in the endRequst handler

```
$(function{

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(AfterPostBack);

    AfterPostBack();

});

function AfterPostback(){

   // Your code goes here...
}
```